# How to prove that Re(zeta(1+i/n)) is equal to the euler constant as n -> infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have noticed that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \Re\left[\zeta\left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)\right] = \gamma$

How can this be proven?

Comment: $\zeta(1+i/n) = \frac{1}{1+i/n-1} + \gamma + O(i/n)$

Comment: @reuns I'm not familiar with this identity, can you please add a link to a proof?

Comment: $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma + O(s)$ (big O notation) it follows from $\zeta(s) = s \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx$ and $\lim_{ s \to 1}\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s} - \int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx =\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{ s \to 1}\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s} - \int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx$